# jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named error when trying to createEntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to setup a backend with an eclipse Dynamic Web Project, and this backend will access a MariaDB using Hibernate ORM. I'm having an issue when creating the Entity Manager Factory. Here is the structure of my project :
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOm0T.png)

Here is the list of the librairies I've included :
[Librairies 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti9vr.png)
[Librairies 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b0UV.png)

Here is the content of my web.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
  <display-name>trakteur-backend2</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the content of my persistence.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class> entities.TrakteurFilm </class>
        <class> entities.TrakteurUser </class>
        <class> entities.TrakteurComment </class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trakteur?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"
                value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"
                value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My DAO class is just the following for now :

```java
package jpaDAO;

import java.util.List;

import entities.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

public class DAO{
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    
    public DAO()
    {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistUnit");
    }
    
    public EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

The error I'm having when executing the project on my Tomcat 10 server is the following :

```
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistUnit
    jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    jpaDAO.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:13)
    service.ServiceTrakteur.<clinit>(ServiceTrakteur.java:14)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1356)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:248)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:342)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:769)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:732)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:702)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:247)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I am getting this error no matter what methods are in my DAO or no matter what REST request I do from my service package.

What I am sure of is that it comes from the line `emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistUnit");` in my DAO, because if I remove this line, all my methods (that don't need to use the DB obviously) work. With this line, none of them work.

I can't find where I failed with my setup. I searched a lot on this issue but I don't find cases that correspond to mine. Apparently, it appears that the persistence.xml or the persistence unit can't be found, but it's here and without error. My object classes (TrakteurComment, TrakteurUser and TrakteurFilm) don't have any error.

Do you have an idea of what it could be ?
Thanks in advance for any help or any answer.
Have a great day

Comment: Not sure what you mean by it is there without error - the only time you are using that file is in the createEntityManagerFactory line. As your research shows, this is commonly because it isn't found on the class path, so it isn't visible to the class loader used to load your DAO class. The persistence xml has to do with your DAO and entities, so I don't know why you'd have it under the webapp, or how it is getting packed up for deployment, but check your jar file structure on deployment to be sure they are all in the same one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I mean by "without error" is a mistake on my part. I just mean that Eclipse doesn't throw any immediate syntax error. That's all. I tried multiple places for the persistence.xml. I tried under /src/main/META-INF/, src/META-INF, src/main/webapp/META-INF. I always get that error.

Comment: Also, how can I check file structure on deployment ? It is deployed directly to my tomcat server run by eclipse.

Comment: @SaladCesar persistence.xml should be in src/main/resources/META-INF/ ie META_INF is inside resources directory

Answer (score 1):

It could be because in your persistence.xml you're specifying version 2.2 (which is an old javax version) and Jakarta is 3.x. I'm assuming this is Hibernate 6. See here: https://itnext.io/whats-new-in-jakarta-persistence-3-1-by-examples-81b292e8b3a4